# jQuery get table with most rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, row

I have several tables in my document. How do I get the "id" of the table that has the most table rows?

```html
<table id="1">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<table id="2">
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>

<table id="3">
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could try something like this:

```
function getLargestTable() {
  var curr=0,max=0, id;
  $('table').each(function(){
    curr = $(this); 
    len = curr.find('tr').length;
    if (len > max) { 
       max=len; 
       id=curr.attr('id');
    }
  });
  return id;
}
```

Probably not the greatest code in the world but it should work;

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I replaced "i" with "$(this) and id with "attr('id')".

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution I could come up with:

```
var result = $("table")
    .sort(function(a, b) { return $(b).find("tr").length - $(a).find("tr").length; })
    .first()
    .attr("Id");
```